# Get exact time of a posted YouTube comment

Tags: time, youtube, youtube-api, comments

I didn't found any info on that.

For example, when you look at YouTube comments there is a timestamp next to it saying "1 hours ago".

Now is "1 hours ago" not a precise time indication. It could be anything from 1h00min to 1h59min.

So is it possible to get the excat time of a posted YouTube comment, like 'Wednesday 18, 9:36'?

---

### Edit

Here is my solution to get both the exact and modified time:

`https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/comments?part=snippet&fields=items(snippet/publishedAt,snippet/updatedAt)&id={COMMENT_ID}&key={YOUR_API_KEY}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. The API returns the full datetimes, as you can see in the json here:

```
"publishedAt": datetime,
"updatedAt": datetime
```

https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/comments#resource